# Application-defined or object-defined error (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I keep getting the annoying error message: Application-defined or object-defined error (VBA).

Background: I have a worksheet that contains rows and columns (some rows & columns are merged), I have a button on the worksheet that I would like to use to validate the worksheet e.g. to report any errors if a cell is not filled in i.e. empty. In additions, I  would like empty cells to become red when the button is clicked on an a particular range of cells contain no values.

I created a VBA Bean to hold all rows of data that are pulled from the worksheet. This class will contain procedures and/or functions that validate the class and hopefully report back to the user any errors encountered. The button calls the print_cheque_Click()  (worksheet code below). Any suggestions here would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

line where error is occurring: **Range(cCel).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)**

error

```
Public Sub validate()
                Dim str As String
                Dim cCel As String
                Dim WS As Worksheet

                Set WS = Worksheets("EFF_PAYROLL")
                WS.Select
                With Selection

                    If Me.getJournalYear = "" Then
                        cCel = Me.getJournalYearCell
                        **Range(cCel).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)**

                    Else
                        **Range(cCel).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)**
                    End If

                End With

            End Sub
```

class employee

```
            Option Explicit


            '****************************
            'class definition of Employee
            'VBA Bean
            '****************************

            '******************
            'private Attributes
            '******************
            Private eID As Integer

            Private jYear As String
            Private jYearCell As String

            Private eRegion As String
            Private eRegionCell As String

            Private eDistrict As String
            Private eDistrictCell As String

            Private eJournalNumber As String
            Private eJournalNumberCell As String

            Private eName As String
            Private eNameCell As String

            Private class_code As String
            Private class_codeCell As String

            Private hourly_rate As String
            Private hourly_rateCell As String

            Private eCertNumber As String
            Private eCertNumberCell As String

            Private eRegRate As String
            Private eRegRateCell As String

            Private eRegHours As String
            Private eRegHoursCell As String

            Private eOvertimeRate As String
            Private eOvertimeRateCell As String

            Private eOvertimeHours As String
            Private eOvertimeHoursCell As String

            Private eRegTotal As String
            Private eRegTotalCell As String

            Private eOvertimeTotal As String
            Private eOvertimeTotalCell As String

            Private eVacationTotal As String
            Private eVacactionTotalCell As String

            Private eTotalPay As String
            Private eTotalPayCell As String

            Private eCommissary As String
            Private eCommissaryCell As String

            Private eTotalCommissary As String
            Private eTotalCommissaryCell As String

            Private eNetPay As String
            Private eNetPayCell As String

            Private eDay As String
            Private eDayCell As String

            Private eMonth As String
            Private eMonthCell As String

            Private eYear As String
            Private eYearCell As String

            Private eChequeNo As String
            Private eChequeNoCell As String

            Private eAddress1 As String
            Private eAddress1Cell As String

            Private eAddress2 As String
            Private eAddress2Cell As String

            Private eAuthorizedOfficer As String
            Private eAuthorizedOfficerCell As String

            Private ePrintedName As String
            Private ePrintedNameCell As String

            Private ePreparedBy As String
            Private ePreparedByCell As String


            '***************
            'Get/Set Methods
            '***************

            '*******************************************
            'eID section
            Public Property Get getID() As String
                getID = eID
            End Property
            Public Property Let setID(value As String)
                setID = value
            End Property
            'END eID section
            '*******************************************


            'journal year
            Public Property Get getJournalYear() As String
                getJournalYear = jYear
            End Property
            Public Property Let setJournalYear(value As String)
                jYear = value
            End Property
            'end journal year


            'setJournalYearCell
            Public Property Get getJournalYearCell() As String
                getJournalYearCell = jYearCell
            End Property

            Public Property Let setJournalYearCell(value As String)
                jYearCell = value
            End Property
            'end setJournalYearCell



            'class code
            Public Property Get getClassCode() As String
                getClassCode = class_code
            End Property


            Public Property Let setClassCode(value As String)
                class_code = value
            End Property
            'end class code

            'class code cell
            Public Property Get getClassCodeCell() As String
                getClassCodeCell = class_codeCell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setClassCodeCell(value As String)
                class_codeCell = value
            End Property
            'end class code code cell


            'hourly rate
            Public Property Get getHourlyRate() As String
                getHourlyRate = hourly_rate
            End Property

            Public Property Let setHourlyRate(value As String)
                hourly_rate = value
            End Property
            'end hourly rate

            'hourly rate cell
            Public Property Get getHourlyRatCell() As String
                getHourlyRateCell = hourly_rateCell
            End Property

            Public Property Let setHourlyRateCell(value As String)
                hourly_rateCell = value
            End Property
            'end hourly rate cell



            'chequeNo
            Public Property Get getChequeNo() As String
                getChequeNo = eChequeNo
            End Property
            Public Property Let setchequeNo(value As String)
                eChequeNo = value
            End Property
            'end chequeNo

            'chequeNoCell
            Public Property Get getChequeNoCell() As String
                getChequeNoCell = eChequeNoCell
            End Property

            Public Property Let setChequeNoCell(value As String)
                eChequeNoCell = value
            End Property
            'end chequeCell



            'prepredBy
            Public Property Get getPreparedBy() As String
                getPreparedBy = ePreparedBy
            End Property

            Public Property Let setPreparedBy(value As String)
                ePreparedBy = value
            End Property
            'end preparedBy

            'preparedByCell
            Public Property Get getPreparedByCell() As String
                getPreparedByCell = ePreparedByCell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setPreparedByCell(value As String)
                ePreparedByCell = value
            End Property
            'end preparedByCell


            'region
            Public Property Get getRegion() As String
                getRegion = eRegion
            End Property
            Public Property Let setRegion(value As String)
                eRegion = value
            End Property
            'end region

            'regionCell
            Public Property Get getRegionCell() As String
                getRegionCell = eRegionCell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setRegionCell(value As String)
                eRegionCell = value
            End Property
            'end regionCell
            'BEGIN

            'district
            Public Property Get getDistrict() As String
                getDistrict = eDistrict
            End Property
            Public Property Let setDistrict(value As String)
                eDistrict = value
            End Property
            'end district

            'districtCell
            Public Property Get getDistrictCell() As String
                getDistrictCell = eDistrictCell
            End Property

            Public Property Let setDistrictCell(value As String)
                eDistrictCell = value
            End Property
            'end districtCell


            'eYear section
            Public Property Get getYear() As String
                getYear = eYear
            End Property
            Public Property Let setYear(value As String)
                eYear = value
            End Property
            'END eYear Section

            'eYearCell
            Public Property Get getEYearCell() As String
                getEYearCell = eYearCell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setEYearCell(value As String)
                eYearCell = value
            End Property
            'end eYearCell


            'eMonth section
            Public Property Get getMonth() As String
                getMonth = eMonth
            End Property
            Public Property Let setMonth(value As String)
                eMonth = value
            End Property
            'END eMonth Section

            'eMonthCell
            Public Property Get getEMonthCell() As String
                getEMonthCell = eMonthCell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setEMonthCell(value As String)
                eMonthCell = value
            End Property
            'end eMonthCell




            'eDay section
            Public Property Get getDay() As String
                getDay = eDay
            End Property
            Public Property Let setDay(value As String)
                eDay = value
            End Property
            'END eDay Section

            'eDayCell
            Public Property Get getEDayCell() As String
                getEDayCell = eDayCell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setEDayCell(value As String)
                eDayCell = value
            End Property
            'end eDayCell

            'eJournalNumber section
            Public Property Get getJournalNumber() As String
                getJournalNumber = eJournalNumber
            End Property
            Public Property Let setJournalNumber(value As String)
                eJournalNumber = value
            End Property
            'end journal number


            'eJournalNumberCell
            Public Property Get getJournalNumberCell() As String
                getJournalNumberCell = eJournalNumberCell
            End Property

            Public Property Let setJournalNumberCell(value As String)
                eJournalNumberCell = value
            End Property
            'end eJournalNumberCell



            'eName Section
            Public Property Get getName() As String
                getName = eName
            End Property

            Public Property Let setName(value As String)
                eName = value
            End Property
            'END eName section

            'eNameCell
            Public Property Get getNameCell() As String
                getNameCell = eNameCell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setNameCell(value As String)
                eNameCell = value
            End Property
            'end eNameCell


            'address1
            Public Property Get getAddress1() As String
                getAddress1 = eAddress1
            End Property

            Public Property Let setAddress1(value As String)
                eAddress1 = value
            End Property
            'end address1

            'adress1Cell
            Public Property Get getAddress1Cell() As String
                getAddress1Cell = eAddress1Cell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setAAddress1Cell(value As String)
                eAddress1Cell = value
            End Property
            'end address1Cell


            'address2
            Public Property Get getAddress2() As String
                getAddress2 = eAddress2
            End Property

            Public Property Let setAddress2(value As String)
                eAddress2 = value
            End Property
            'end address2

            'address2Cell
            Public Property Get getAddress2Cell() As String
                getAddress2Cell = eAddress2
            End Property
            Public Property Let setAddress2cell(value As String)
                eAddress2Cell = value
            End Property
            'end address2Cell


            'certNumber
            Public Property Get getCertNumber() As String
                getCertNumber = eCertNumber
            End Property

            Public Property Let setCertNumber(value As String)
                eCertNumber = value
            End Property
            'end certNumber

            'certNumberCell
            Public Property Get getCertNumberCell() As String
                getCertNumberCell = eCertNumberCell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setCertNumberCell(value As String)
                eCertNumberCell = value
            End Property
            'end CertNumberCell


            'regRate
            Public Property Get getRegRate() As String
                getRegRate = eRegRate
            End Property

            Public Property Let setRegRate(value As String)
                eRegRate = value
            End Property
            'end regRate


            'regRateCell
            Public Property Get getRegRateCell() As String
                getRegRateCell = eRegRateCell
            End Property

            Public Property Let setRegRateCell(value As String)
                eRegRateCell = value
            End Property
            'end regRateCell


            'regHours
            Public Property Get getRegHours() As String
                getRegHours = eRegHours
            End Property

            Public Property Let setRegHours(value As String)
                eRegHours = value
            End Property
            'end regHours

            'regHoursCell
            Public Property Get getRegHoursCell() As String
                getRegHours = eRegHoursCell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setRegHoursCell(value As String)
                eRegHoursCell = value
            End Property
            'end regHoursCell

            'overtimeRate
            Public Property Get getOvertimeRate() As String
                getOvertimeRate = eOvertimeRate
            End Property

            Public Property Let setOvertimeRate(value As String)
                eOvertimeRate = value
            End Property
            'end overtimeRate

            'overtimeRateCell
            Public Property Get getOvertimeRateCell() As String
                getOvertimeRateCell = eOvertimeRateCell
            End Property
            'end

            Public Property Let setOvertimeRateCell(value As String)
                eOvertimeRateCell = value
            End Property
            'end overtimeRateCell


            'overtimeHours
            Public Property Get getOvertimeHours() As String
                getOvertimeHours = eOvertimeHours
            End Property

            Public Property Let setOvertimeHours(value As String)
                eOvertimeHours = value
            End Property
            'end overtimeHours

            'overtimeHoursCell
            Public Property Get getOvertimeHoursCell() As String
                getOvertimeHoursCell = eOvertimeHoursCell
            End Property

            Public Property Let setOvertimeHoursCell(value As String)
                eOvertimeHoursCell = value
            End Property
            'end overtimeHoursCell


            'regTotal
            Public Property Get getRegTotal() As String
                getRegTotal = eRegTotal
            End Property

            Public Property Let setRegTotal(value As String)
                eRegTotal = value
            End Property
            'end regTotal

            'regTotalCell
            Public Property Get getRegTotalCell() As String
                getRegTotalCell = eRegTotalCell
            End Property

            Public Property Let setRegTotalCell(value As String)
                eRegTotalCell = value
            End Property
            'end regTotalCell


            'overtimeTotal
            Public Property Get getOvertimeTotal() As String
                getOvertimeTotal = eOvertimeTotal
            End Property

            Public Property Let setOvertimeTotal(value As String)
                eOvertimeTotal = value
            End Property
            'end overtimeTotal

            'overtimeTotalCell
            Public Property Get getOvertimeTotalCell() As String
                getOvertimeTotalCell = eOvertimeTotalCell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setOvertimeTotalCell(value As String)
                eOvertimeTotalCell = value
            End Property
            'end overtimeTotalCell


            'vacationTotal
            Public Property Get getVacationTotal() As String
                getVacationTotal = eVacationTotal
            End Property

            Public Property Let setVacationTotal(value As String)
                eVacationTotal = value
            End Property
            'end vacationTotal

            'vacationTotalCell
            Public Property Get getVacationTotalCell() As String
                getVacationTotalCell = eVacationTotalCell
            End Property

            Public Property Let setVacationTotalCell(value As String)
                eVacationTotalCell = value
            End Property
            'end vacationTotalCell


            'totalPay
            Public Property Get getTotalPay() As String
                getTotalPay = eTotalPay
            End Property

            Public Property Let setTotalPay(value As String)
                eTotalPay = value
            End Property
            'end totalPay


            'totalPayCell
            Public Property Get getTotalPayCell() As String
                getTotalPayCell = eTotalPayCell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setTotalPayCell(value As String)
                eTotalPayCell = value
            End Property
            'end totalPayCell


            'revisit
            '************ buffer issue ? ********************
            'commissary
            Public Property Get getCommissary() As String
                getCommissary = eCommissary
            End Property

            Public Property Let setCommissary(value As String)
                eCommissary = value
            End Property
            'end commissary


            'commissary
            Public Property Get getCommissaryCell() As String
                getCommissaryCell = eCommissaryCell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setCommissaryCell(value As String)
                eCommissaryCell = value
            End Property
            'end commissary




            'totalCommissary
            Public Property Get getTotalCommissary() As String
                getTotalCommissary = eTotalCommissary
            End Property

            Public Property Let setTotalCommissary(value As String)
                eTotalCommissary = value
            End Property
            'end totalCommissary

            'totalCommissaryCell
            Public Property Get getTotalCommissaryCell() As String
                getTotalCommissaryCell = eTotalCommissary
            End Property
            Public Property Let setTotalCommissaryCell(value As String)
                eTotalCommissaryCell = value
            End Property
            'end totalCommissaryCell


            'netPay
            Public Property Get getNetPay() As String
                getNetPay = eNetPay
            End Property

            Public Property Let setNetPay(value As String)
                eNetPay = value
            End Property
            'end netPay

            'netPayCell
            Public Property Get getNetPayCell() As String
                getNetPayCell = eNetPayCell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setNetPayCell(value As String)
                eNetPayCell = value
            End Property
            'end netPayCell


            'authorizedOfficer
            Public Property Get getAuthorizedOfficer() As String
                getAuthorizedOfficer = eAuthorizedOfficer
            End Property

            Public Property Let setAuthorizedOfficer(value As String)
                eAuthorizedOfficer = value
            End Property
            'end authorizedOfficer

            'authorizedOfficerCell
            Public Property Get getAuthorizedOfficerCell() As String
                getAuthorizedOfficerCelll = eAuthorizedOfficerCell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setAuthorizedOfficerCell(value As String)
                eAuthorizedOfficerCell = value
            End Property
            'end authorizedOfficer


            'printedName
            Public Property Get getPrintedName() As String
                getPrintedName = ePrintedName
            End Property

            Public Property Let setPrintedName(value As String)
                ePrintedName = value
            End Property
            'end printedName

            'printedNameCell
            Public Property Get getPrintedNameCell() As String
                getPrintedNameCell = ePrintedNameCell
            End Property
            Public Property Let setPritnedNameCell(value As String)
                ePrintedNameCell = value
            End Property
            'end printedNameCell



            '***************
            'Procedure / Function
            '***************
            Public Sub validate()
                Dim str As String
                Dim cCel As String
                Dim WS As Worksheet

                Set WS = Worksheets("EFF_PAYROLL")
                WS.Select
                With Selection

                    If Me.getJournalYear = "" Then
                        cCel = Me.getJournalYearCell
                        Range(cCel).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

                    Else
                        Range(cCel).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                    End If

                End With

            End Sub



            'constructor
            Private Sub Class_Initialize()
                'assign an ID to each new employee object
                eID = eID + 1
            End Sub
            'end constructor
```

worksheet code

```
            Private Sub print_cheque_Click()

                Dim template As Worksheet
                Dim rng As Range
                Dim journal As Range
                Dim iReply As Integer


                Dim row As Range
                Dim cell As Range
                Dim employeeCollection As Collection
                Set employeeCollection = New Collection


                'EFF_PAYROLL fields
                Dim dayStr As String
                Dim monthStr As String

                'boolean flag - if error is raised don't print cheque
                Dim errorFlag As Boolean
                errorFlag = True 'raise error if no fields are filled in

                Dim str As String




                '*************************
                'work with Employee Object
                '*************************

                'find the number of cheques to be created by cheque number
                Set rng = Sheets("EFF_PAYROLL").Range("a7:a35")


                'define employee object
                Dim emp As employee


                '********local variables **********
                '**********************************
                Dim year As String
                Dim cell_address As String
                Dim name As String



                For Each row In rng.Rows

                    'create new employee foreach row
                    Set emp = New employee


                    For Each cell In row.Cells







                        '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                        'grab all values from payroll_journal
                        'populate VBA Bean - Employee Type
                        '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++



                        '*** header info *******************************************
                        emp.setJournalYear = Sheets("EFF_PAYROLL").Range("O3").value
                        emp.setJournalYearCell = "O3"

                        emp.setRegion = Sheets("EFF_PAYROLL").Range("P3").value
                        emp.setRegionCell = "P3"

                        emp.setDistrict = Sheets("EFF_PAYROLL").Range("Q3").value
                        emp.setDistrictCell = "Q3"

                        emp.setJournalNumber = Sheets("EFF_PAYROLL").Range("R3").value
                        emp.setJournalNumberCell = "R3"
                        '*** end header info *****************************************




                        '*** employee line item **************************************
                        emp.setName = cell.value
                        emp.setNameCell = cell.Address

                        emp.setClassCode = cell.Offset(0, 1)
                        emp.setClassCodeCell = cell.Offset(0, 1).Address

                        emp.setHourlyRate = cell.Offset(0, 2)
                        emp.setHourlyRateCell = cell.Offset(0, 2).Address

                        emp.setCertNumber = cell.Offset(0, 3)
                        emp.setCertNumberCell = cell.Offset(0, 3).Address

                        emp.setCommissary = cell.Offset(0, 46)
                        emp.setCommissaryCell = cell.Offset(0, 46).Address

                        emp.setTotalCommissary = cell.Offset(0, 46)
                        emp.setTotalCommissaryCell = cell.Offset(0, 46).Address

                        emp.setDay = cell.Offset(0, 51)
                        emp.setEDayCell = cell.Offset(0, 51).Address

                        emp.setMonth = cell.Offset(0, 52)
                        emp.setEMonthCell = cell.Offset(0, 52).Address

                        emp.setYear = cell.Offset(0, 53)
                        emp.setEYearCell = cell.Offset(0, 52).Address

                        emp.setchequeNo = cell.Offset(0, 54)
                        emp.setChequeNoCell = cell.Offset(0, 54).Address

                        emp.setAddress1 = cell.Offset(0, 57)
                        emp.setAAddress1Cell = cell.Offset(0, 57).Address

                        emp.setAddress2 = cell.Offset(1, 57)
                        emp.setAddress2cell = cell.Offset(1, 57).Address

                        '*** end employee line item *********************************


                        '*************footer info ***********************************
                        emp.setPreparedBy = Sheets("EFF_PAYROLL").Range("J39").value
                        emp.setPreparedByCell = Sheets("EFF_PAYROLL").Range("J39").Address

                        emp.setAuthorizedOfficer = Sheets("EFF_PAYROLL").Range("AE39").value
                        emp.setAuthorizedOfficerCell = Sheets("EFF_PAYROLL").Range("AE39").Address

                        emp.setPrintedName = Sheets("EFF_PAYROLL").Range("AD44").value
                        emp.setPritnedNameCell = Sheets("EFF_PAYROLL").Range("AD44").Address
                        '*************end footer info *******************************



                        employeeCollection.Add emp

            '            For Each emp In employeeCollection
            '                Debug.Print emp.getID & " " & emp.getName _
            '                ; vbCrLf & emp.getClassCode & " " _
            '                ; emp.getClassCodeCell
            '
            '
            '            Next emp
            '
            '
            '            Debug.Print employeeCollection.Count
            '

                        '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
                        'END fetch of data from payroll_journal
                        '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++





            '            If Not IsEmpty(cell.value) And errorFlag = False Then
            '
            '
            '
            '                'unprotect worksheets during writing process
            '                unProtectWS ("Cheque Template")
            '
            '                ' unprotect workbook
            '                ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect ("***")
            '
            '
            '                Sheets("Cheque Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            '                ActiveSheet.name = emp.name
            '
            '
            '
            '
            '                '******
            '                '** populate cheque with corresponding values - cell.Value
            '                '******
            '                'Sheets(employee_name).Range("B7").Value = employee_name
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("B7").value = emp.name
            '
            '
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("D4").value = dayStr
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("C4").value = monthStr
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("B4").value = emp.year
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("H8").value = emp.certNumber
            '
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("B8").value = emp.address1
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("B9").value = emp.address2
            '
            '                'journal number
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("H4").value = emp.year
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("I4").value = emp.region
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("J4").value = emp.district
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("K4").value = emp.journalNumber
            '                'end journal number
            '
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("B14").value = emp.regRate
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("F14").value = emp.regHours
            '
            '                'overtime hours and rate
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("B16").value = emp.overtimeRate
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("F16").value = emp.overtimeHours
            '                'END overtime hours and rate
            '
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("H14").value = emp.regTotal
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("H16").value = emp.overtimeTotal
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("B24").value = emp.commissary
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("H24").value = emp.totalCommissary
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("H18").value = emp.vacationTotal
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("H20").value = emp.totalPay
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("H29").value = emp.netPay
            '
            '                'cheque printout (bottom)
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("B47").value = emp.name
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("B48").value = emp.address1
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("B49").value = emp.address2
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("B43").value = Module3.SpellNumber(emp.netPay)
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("K45").value = Round(emp.netPay, 2)
            '
            '                'month and str on cheque portion
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("K40").value = emp.year & "/" & monthStr & "/" & dayStr
            '
            '                'printed name aka persons that approves cheque
            '                Sheets(emp.name).Range("J51").value = emp.printedName
            '
            '
            '
            '
            '
            '
            '                'For Each emp In employeeCollection
            '                    ' Perform validation on that employee
            '                 '   Debug.Print emp.Name
            '                'Next emp
            '
            '
            '
            '
            '
            '
            '
            '
            '
            '
            '                'Module6.printWorksheet (emp.name)
            '                'Module6.deleteWorksheet (emp.name)
            '
            '
            '
            '                'protect/lock cheque template before closing
            '
            '                'protectWS ("EFF_PAYROLL")
            '                protectWS ("Cheque Template")
            '
            '                'protect/lock workbook before closing
            '                ActiveWorkbook.Protect ("***")
            '
            '                'add employee to collection - used for later use
            '                'employeeCollection.Add emp
            '
            '
            '                'MsgBox "Cheque(s) will be printed."
            '
            '
            '            End If
                    Next cell

                Next row
               emp.validate

                Exit Sub
            End Sub
```

Comment: out of curiosity as google didn't turn up anything definitive, what do you mean by VBA Bean? Never heard the phrase before. Also, noone can really work out what is going wrong unless you tell us the line the error is raised on (when the error is raised, click debug and tell us the line the VBE shows you). The particular error message is very generic and raised by a lot of things for a lot of issues.

Comment: Not sure if there is such a thing in VBA. I got the term from my Java programming days, where a Java bean was nothing more than an object that contained properties and attributes i.e. basically a collection of data other objects could manipulate.

Comment: ahh, ok, so it doesn't *do* much (i.e. methods) but is a class of properties essentially to store the info related to the conceptual unit. Makes sense.

Comment: **1048 lines of code!**.. why not put only relevant part of code??

Comment: In the code above the method will do something it will validate the employee object - at-least this is what I am trying to accomplish. a method that doesn't do anything doesn't need to be included in the class definition.

Comment: also, in case you are having difficulty working out the exact line the error is on, go to Tools>Options and set to "Break on Class errors" or something like that. By default otherwise it would show the error as being on the line in the standard module that called the class.

Comment: What is the value of `cCel` when error occurs? It looks like it is invalid and causing the error when you try to access `Range(cCel).Interior.Color`.

Comment: O3 is the value I recieve when issuing debug.print cCel oddly the value isn't enclosed in quotation marks - could this be the reason its throwing an error?

Comment: If `cCel` is not a valid range (or cell) reference, then it will cause this error.

Comment: I understand this, I am trying to create a range by passing in a string value of the cell e.g. O3

Comment: I have confirmated "O3" to be the cell I want to act on in this example, not sure why I am still getting this error.

Comment: Is that cell in a protected range? The code works fine for me but if the range is protected, it will throw that error.

Comment: lol, thanks a bunch. I guess I was looking at this way too long. Thanks all that makes sense :)

Comment: @Michael if this solves the problem, please mark my answer below as "Accepted". In this way, your question (and the solution) can help others who may face similar problems in the future. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I notice in your code you have some lines commented out that previously appeared to have protected/unprotected the worksheet.  If the sheet is still in a protected state, you will not be able to do this operation, and it will raise the 1004 error.

**Solution**

Unprotect the sheet (manually or via code) before formatting the cell.

OR, in the protection dialog, ensure that users are allowed to format cells:

[image]

Comment: Nice one David. That is 1048 lines and still you didn't fail to notice the protection. If it was me, I'd go lazy reading the whole post and fell asleep! :D

Comment: @L42 TBH I totally skimmed this Q the first time through -- I didn't come close to trying to read all 1048 lines :) Once I saw the comments and the offending line, I tried a few things and then vaguely remembered seeing `Protection` in there somewhere.